# Changing button colour using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, cgi

I have this html, that uses a bit of Javascript. I am trying to change the colour of the button using CSS. The CSS is in a file called getreplies.css and contains

```css
.button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="getreplies.css">
</head>
<input class="button" type="button" onclick="location.href='path/messages.pl?name=<TMPL_VAR NAME=name>&page=<TMPL_VAR NAME=page>';" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=page>">

</html>
```

But it doesn't work. I don't see any changes. Also, can someone tell me how I can centre these buttons using CSS as well? Thanks for any help!

P.S. if it helps, then I am doing this within a perl cgi script.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided in the question works in isolation.

Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Look at the response for the request for `getreplies.css`.

You will probably see a 500 Internal Server Error.

(Since you haven't done this debugging I'm going to assume that that is the case as this is the most likely explanation for what you are seeing)

> if it helps, then I am doing this within a perl cgi script

A typical configuration for CGI is to specify that a directory (often `/cgi-bin/`) contains CGI scripts and **only** CGI scripts.

Since `getreplies.css` is a relative URI, if your script is `/cgi-bin/example.cgi` then your stylesheet will be `/cgi-bin/getreplies.css` and your web server will attempt to execute it as a CGI script.

Since it isn't executable, this fails.

Move the stylesheet out of the `cgi-bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```js
function setColor(e) {
   var target = e.target,
       status = e.target.classList.contains('active');

   e.target.classList.add(status ? 'inactive' : 'active');
   e.target.classList.remove(status ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #7FFF00;  
}
.inactive {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="getreplies.css">
</head>
<input 
  type="button" 
  id="button" 
  value="button" 
  style="color:blue" 
  onclick="setColor(event)"; 
  data-count="1" 
/>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've spelt button wrong in your css.

```
.buton{
color: red;}
```

should be.

```
.button{
color: red;}
```

Lee.

Comment: ah yep, that was a typo. Sorry about that. Even after changing it, it doesn't work.

Comment: I pasted 
`html{
 background-color: #FEF9E7;
}`

but nothing happened.

Answer (score -1):

To style your button you should use `input[type=button] {color: red; }`

Or change the class name `.button` to something else lime `.mybutton`

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `background-color` instead of `color`, example:

```
.button{
    background-color: red;
}
```